# Access Laravel API from a Laravel Nova custom tool

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-6, laravel-nova

I have created a new tool within Nova and I have to access my laravel api defined in `/routes/api.php` not the one in `nova-components/component-name/routes/api.php`

My code within the Vue component looks like this:

```
getCertificateTypes() {
    Nova.request().get('/api/certificate-type')
       .then(response => {
           // my code
       });
},
```

This returns a 401 Unauthorized

This is what I tried so far:

Added this code to my routes() function in the ServiceProvider of the tool created

```
Route::middleware(['nova', Authorize::class])
        ->prefix('laravel')
        ->group(__DIR__.'/../../../routes/api.php');
```

Now, if I call `Nova.request().get('/laravel/api/certificate-type')` I get a 404 not found.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is the routes method called in the service provider and is your serivce provider getting called? How does your routes/api.php look like?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your question eventually? I am facing something similar at the moment.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I just created a new controller in Nova which will get the data through the backend and call that controller.